# equivalence between $K^b(\mathcal{P}) $ and $ D^{b}(\mathcal{P})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, functors, derived-categories

In my homological algebra notes I found the proof that the homotopy category $K^{-}(\mathcal{P})$ is equivalent to the derived category $D^{-}(\mathcal{A})$ when $\mathcal{A}$ has enough projectives.

The proof essentially relies on the following:

> Lemma: Every quasi isomorphism of $K^{-}(\mathcal{P})$ is an
> isomorphism.
>
> Lemma: Given a complex $A^{\bullet}$ in the category of complexes
> $C(\mathcal{A})$ then there exists a complex $P^{\bullet}$
> and a quasi isomorphism between $P^{\bullet}$ and
> $A^{\bullet}$ with $P^{\bullet}$ having projective terms.

I was wondering whether this result could be extended to $K^{b}(\mathcal{P})$ is equivalent to $D^{b}(\mathcal{A})$. I can't quite imply an immediate generalization. Is this a well-known fact?

Any help would be appreciated, any other proof supporting the truthfulness of the fact would be welcomed.

Comment: The proof states that the canonical functor $K^{-}(\mathcal{P}) \rightarrow D^{-}(\mathcal{A})$ is an equivalence of categories. I’d say that this is an equivalence of categories $K^{b} \rightarrow D^b$ iff it is essentially surjective, ie every bounded complex in $\mathcal{A}$ is quasi-isomorphic to a bounded complex in $\mathcal{P}$. This clearly implies that $\mathcal{A}$ has finite projective dimension. I think this is also a sufficient condition, but I’m not totally sure.

Comment: You should add the definition of $\mathcal{P}$.